# rails open child window and open parent window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

On a submit button click, I want to open a child window and redirect the parent window to another location.

To do that, I have used the code for opening child window:

```
<button class="btnBg" onclick="window.open('<%= url_for(:action=>"index") %>', '', 'toolbars=0')">
```

Can you please tell me how to redirect the parent window to a desired location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign something to `window.location` in your JavaScript (but be sure to do that **after** opening your new window):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_and_redirect() {
        window.open('<%= url_for(:action=>"index") %>', '', 'toolbars=0');
        window.location = 'the new location for the parent window';
    }
</script>
<button class="btnBg" onclick="open_and_redirect()">
```

You don't need to use a separate function though, I just did that to make it easier to read.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have another question, is it possible to close child through ruby code, ie. after clicking finish btn in child window it will redirect to a action, and from inside that action i want to close the child  window

Comment: @lamrin: No, the Ruby code runs on your server but you want to do something on the client, you'll have to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: this is my code  "    $('#finishBtn').click(function(){

      var target = '<%= calculation_path(:score=>@score) %>';
            $('#class_form').attr('action', target);
            $('#class_form').submit();
           });    "  here, when i click the finish button it will redirect to action called "calculation", and what i need is, after redirected to calculation_path child window should be closed.. please tell me how to do this,  thanks

Comment: @lamrin: You could include a `<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>` bit of JavaScript in the HTML that the form returns, the form's return HTML should go to the new window and `window.close()` will close it.

Answer (score 2):

In you child window, trigger the following code by event or timer:

```
opener.location = "http://example.com" 
window.close();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have another question, is it possible to close child through ruby code, ie. after clicking finish btn in child window it will redirect to a action, and from inside that action i want to close the child window

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in two ways:

1. Append the url you want to redirect to the onclick event, as the other posts show.
2. Use the popup to set the location of the parent window with `window.parent.location = 'some url'`

Comment: thanks a lot, i have another question, is it possible to close child through ruby code, ie. after clicking finish btn in child window it will redirect to a action, and from inside that action i want to close the child window